# How to add multiple tasks of the same type in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin, flatbuffers

I need to generate FlatBuffers files from *.fbs file before the build.
So i'm using `gradle.plugin.io.netifi:gradle-flatbuffers-plugin:1.0.7` to do it for me.

It works as expected for 1 task:

```
def generatedSourcePathJava = "$buildDir/generated/source/flatbuffers/java"
def generatedSourcePathCpp = "$buildDir/generated/source/flatbuffers/cpp"

...

task createFlatBuffersJava(type: io.netifi.flatbuffers.plugin.tasks.FlatBuffers) {
  outputDir = file(generatedSourcePathJava)
  language = "kotlin"
}

build.dependsOn createFlatBuffersJava
```

But if i add the 2nd one (to generate C++ files for JNI):

```
task createFlatBuffersJava(type: io.netifi.flatbuffers.plugin.tasks.FlatBuffers) {
  outputDir = file(generatedSourcePathJava)
  language = "kotlin"
}

task createFlatBuffersCpp(type: io.netifi.flatbuffers.plugin.tasks.FlatBuffers) {
  outputDir = file(generatedSourcePathCpp)
  language = "cpp"
}

assemble.dependsOn createFlatBuffersJava, createFlatBuffersCpp
```

Gradle build (`../gradlew :engine-flatbuffers:clean :engine-flatbuffers:build`) fails with the following:

> - What went wrong:
>   A problem occurred configuring project ':engine-flatbuffers'.
>   java.util.ConcurrentModificationException (no error message)

I think the question can be generalized to "How to add multiple tasks of the same type in Gradle?".

PS. "gradle-5.6-all"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a known plugin bug/feature reported at https://github.com/gregwhitaker/gradle-flatbuffers-plugin/issues/7.

It works in `1.0.5` but `kotlin` [argument] is sadly not supported there at that point. `java` works and it's compatible.